# Correct disposal in IAsyncEnumerable methods?

Tags: c#, iasyncenumerable, iasyncdisposable

The answer to this may be that it's not possible, but the question is: assume you have a C# method for consuming the lines in a `TextReader` that returns `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`. How do you ensure that when `DisposeAsync` is called on the `IAsyncEnumerator<string>` that the `TextReader` is disposed of? Or is this something you need to write a custom implementation to achieve?

Comment: It's not actually the enumeration's job to dispose the `TextReader`, that's the job of whatever created the `TextReader`. Normally you'd expect that code to live in its own `Task` with its own `using`. In theory you could just pass the reader to the enumerator and *make* it responsible, but that would reduce the scenarios it would actually be useful in. Conceptually, enumerators are distinct from the things they're enumerating.

Comment: Note that if you have an iterator method that *itself* creates the `TextReader`, all you need to do is make sure it does a `using var reader = new TextReader(...)`; compiler magic will transform the iterator's using blocks into something called on dispose, just as for non-async iterators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a try-finally block inside the async iterator, or more simply a `using` block, and the `TextReader` will be disposed as soon as the caller completes the enumeration. It doesn't matter if the enumeration will complete normally, or prematurely because of an exception or a `break`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await foreach (var line in GetLines())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

private static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetLines()
{
    var reader = new StringReader("Line1\nLine2\nLine3");
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            if (line == null) break;
            yield return line;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Line1
>   Line2
>   Line3
>   Disposed

Comment: If the foreach is an infinite loop that never ends, the enumerator will not be disposed, and the finally block will not be called. This is the only case I can think of.

Comment: Another case is if a buggy or malicious caller creates an enumerator (by calling the [`GetAsyncEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1.getasyncenumerator) method), and then keep a reference to it in a static field to prevent it from being garbage collected. This possibility is also open for normal (not async) enumerables/enumerators.

Comment: The real case I'm thinking of is if someone just breaks out of the loop because they've got the data they need. (I'm less concerned with bugs/malice.)

Comment: This case is covered. Breaking the `foreach` loop causes the immediate disposal of the enumerator used in the loop, causing the invocation of the finally block inside the iterator.